# Error while copying files from Windows to Ubuntu after Windows update

Tags: dual-boot, filesystem, read-only

I have a dual boot system with windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04.

Until now I could freely copy and paste things from Windows to Ubuntu while accessing Ubuntu.

After a Windows update I can't do it.

I can see them but when I copy them the Ubuntu partition becomes read only with small locks.

Before copying it's not read only. I have unchecked hibernate and fast boot and also run `chkdsk` on my `C:` drive but none of this made any difference.

How should I solve it?

Comment: Thanks for the formatting but how do I solve it

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if the permissions of the folder have changed. You can do this by Right clicking on the blank space > Properties >  Permissions.

Worst attempt, run nautilus in super user mode by 
`sudo nautilus`

Go to permissions again in the same way as above and change the owner and group to your user name and group.

Don't forget to close the super user nautilus window after you are done. It's pretty dangerous :P Destroyed my home folder completely once xD